# Polymer - Change paper-toolbar contents depending on selected iron-page

Tags: javascript, polymer, polymer-1.0, polymer-starter-kit

Expanding on the Polymer Starter Kit I'm struggling to figure out how I can change the hamburger(`menu`) icon to a different button when a different `iron-page` is active.

---

**index.html**

```
<paper-toolbar class="paper-toolbar-0" id="mainToolbar">

  <paper-icon-button id="paperToggle" icon="menu" paper-drawer-toggle></paper-icon-button>
  <!-- more toolbar content here -->

</paper-toolbar>

<iron-pages attr-for-selected="data-route" class="layout vertical center" selected="{{route}}">

  <!-- Top Stories -->     
  <section data-route="topstories">
    <story-list id="story-list" class="layout vertical center-justified"></story-list>
  </section>

   <!-- Item Info -->     
  <section data-route="item-info" class="fullbleed layout center-justified">
    <item-info firebase-item-id="[[params.firebaseitemid]]" class="fullbleed flex"></item-info>
  </section>

</iron-pages>
```

---

When the `item-info` route is selected, I would like to replace the `menu`  `paper-toggle-button` with a `back` button. Possibly changing the toolbar text from the application title to 'Back to Top Stories' say.

Now, I think this is possible by setting an `id` on each of these controls and then have some Javascript in the `item-info` element that makes these changes. I'd prefer something a little more modular as this would tie my `item-info` element very closely to content that is external to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did a custom polymer element to which you pass an array of icons and puts them on the toolbar.

Here is the code:

```
<dom-module id="my-toolbar-icons">
<template>
    <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{contextualButtons}}" as="button" id="buttonsRepeat">
        <paper-icon-button contextual-action="{{button.action}}" icon="{{button.icon}}" on-tap="onContextualButtonTap"></paper-icon-button>
    </template>
</template>

<script>
Polymer({
    is: 'my-toolbar-icons',
    properties: {
        contextualButtons: {
            type: Array,
            value: function () {
                return [];
            }
        }
    },
    ready: function(){
        //set data just to show an icon
        this.contextualButtons = [{ icon: 'social:person-add', action: 'new' }, { icon: 'delete', action: 'delete' }, { icon: 'cloud-upload', action: 'update' }, { icon: 'image:camera-alt', action: 'takephoto' }, { icon: 'search', action: 'search' }];
    },
    setData: function (newContextualButtons) {
        //set data to the array (usage)
        //var item = document.querySelector("#id-of-this-element")
        //item.setData(someArrayOfIcons)
        this.contextualButtons = newContextualButtons;
    },
    onContextualButtonTap: function (event) {
        var item = this.$.buttonsRepeat.itemForElement(event.target);
        this.fire('customize-listener', item.action);
    }
});
</script>
</dom-module>

<!--Usage-->
<my-toolbar-icons id="my-toolbar-icons"></my-toolbar-icons> <!--declaration-->

<!--with javascript-->
this.toolbar= document.querySelector("#my-toolbar-icons");
this.toolbar.setData([{ icon: 'social:person-add', action: 'new' }]);
```

This is just an idea that can be used to make you want to do.

Comment: Neat idea - I can see this coming in handy when you need to cycle between different icons. How are you going to handle transitions between them though? Would be nice to be able to do a nice transition like the YouTube play button transitioning to the pause button.

Comment: To solve my problem with this element was enough. To be honest I was not thinking about how to add transitions to each icon, but as you can realize that there is a listener can execute actions for the corresponding icon, then only necessary to add extra functionality to the listener, well, I think so. By the way, sorry for my English.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that your `paper-toolbar` and your `iron-pages` both reside in the same template, so that both can assess the `route` property. You could easy go along and have an [if-template](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/templates.html#dom-if) or toggle the [hidden parameter of the navigation element](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/data-binding.html#expressions-in-binding-annotations).

Comment: While I've managed to get this working (thanks for the pointer in the right direction) I can't say I'm completely happy with it - for instance I have a function that needs to run on the `back` button's `on-click`. This now needs to be available at the app level.

Comment: u could also do this via custom events. Backbutton throws 'back' event and your app-router listens on document level for this event.